# Show excerpt eithout givr a link or shoe trad mote link

Tags: wordpress

i just just have post and i try to use the excerpt. The problem is i dont want to have a lread more link. I just want too show the paragraph that have been excerpt. How to do that sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_the_excerpt()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) to print an excerpt by specifying a maximium number of characters.

```
// Add below code in your functions.php
function the_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength) {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $charlength++;

    if ( mb_strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength ) {
        $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
        $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
        $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
        if ( $excut < 0 ) {
            echo mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
        } else {
            echo $subex;
        }
        echo '[...]';
    } else {
        echo $excerpt;
    }
}


// Pass character limit to the below function and display whenever you want.
the_excerpt_max_charlength(140);
```